# how to make a list of calculated data from a for loop

Tags: c++

i'm making a programme that calculates the gpa of student which read in data (units per course,matric number, coursework grade, exam grade and evaluation)

i was required to print out the report for each student(which i was able to do), however when i want to list the data( the data requires the matric number and gpa of each student), the function was only able to print the data of the last student in the data.

i have something like this;

```
for (k=0; k< size; k++)
{
    while (input_file >> student[k].matric) 
    { 
        // this is where i read in, calculate and print report for each student
    }
}

print_out(matric, gpa) // this is where the function used to make the list of the students matric num and gpa
```

Comment: Please post a little bit more of your code. What you posted isn't enough to suggest something useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store the data for example in array/vector and then run another loop to print the data or print the data after calculating individual student than run next calculation or just store the data in one string file than print it.